# Error while updating eclipse ADT plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-adt

I am fetching a problem while doing update of my eclipse. It shows below message:

> Some sites could not be found.  See the error log for more detail.
>   Unable to read repository at file:/C:/development/eclipse/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository/cache/content-1736963980.jar.
>   Premature end of file.
>   No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/release/R201209281200/4.2/.
>   Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno.
>   Unable to read repository at file:/C:/development/eclipse/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository/cache/content-1736963980.jar.
>   Premature end of file.

I am using eclipse Juno. It was fine with SDK 22. After update the SDK to 23.0.2 when I am trying to install any update. It shows the above message. It also shows "No update found" message.

Please help me out.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was happened with me is some of ADT Plugin is conflicting. Though when I restart my eclipse, it's shows a dialog with update your ADT Plugin and after *"Check for updates"* its shows *"No update founds"*. It happens every time I restart my eclipse.

So I go to **Help -> Install new software** and tried to update it manually and found that some of ADT Plugins are conflicting. e.g. DDMS, Development Tools, Hierarchy Viewer etc. So I uninstall them.

To uninstall any plugin **Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> Select the plugin -> Uninstall** (You will find that at bottom of the window).

Then I restarted my Eclipse, went to **Help -> Install New Software -> Select ADT Plugin** from drop down menu and updated it.

Then it just working fine with me. May be you can try this with your own risk. Happy coding... :) :) :)